# How to display bootstrap collapse menu in this particular scenario?

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Collapse menu is not displaying on smaller screen. Where I have mistaken? I am using Bootstrap 3. I have jquery and bootstrap.min.js linked properly too but the collapse menu is not appearing.
[image: I want to make it look]

**HTML:**

```
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class ="row ">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
          <a class ="navbar-brand" href=""><img src ="img/summan-company.png" alt="Summan" /></a> </div>
      </div>
      <div class ="row navbar-position">
        <div class="col-md-10 pull-right">
          <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left ">
              <div class="row "> </div>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
                <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or it didn't happen.

Comment: @setek  here is  http://codepen.io/RetinaInc/pen/HmBig

Comment: @Robin jquery is missing

Comment: @SaiRamSudheer haha I was too slow by 2 minutes. Yes, jQuery is missing.

Comment: @SaiRamSudheer and setek I have added jquery but the problem is same.

Comment: @setek it is still same problem . I have added jquery.

Comment: @Robin I've edited your code heavily in trying to diagnose, but this works: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wztdC . your codepen didn't have jQuery (also, jQuery needs to go before `bootstrap.min.js`, did you do it in the right order?

Comment: @setek this is not what I wanted. I want the logo part detached from the navbar. I will update an image please look for it to know what i am looking to do.

Comment: The edit you made is not different than bootstrap original menus. I am trying to customize the look.

Comment: @Robin if you want to use Bootstrap's styles for the `.navbar-toggle` then that element needs to be **inside** `.navbar-default`, it can't be outside it. You can always move your logo outside of `.navbar-header` and style it separately yourself.

Comment: @Robin is this what you want? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yBjux

Comment: @Robin great, and I'm guessing you can take it the rest of the way to "yes exactly"?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your HTML as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href=""><img src ="img/summan-company.png" alt="Summan" /></a></a>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you.

**HTML :**

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class ="row ">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <a class ="navbar-brand" href=""><img src ="img/summan-company.png" alt="Summan" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10 pull-right row navbar-position">
                    <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                               <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
                               <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                               <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                               <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            </button>
                        </div>

                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left ">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
                                <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
                                <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
                                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</header>
```